# Evaluate $\sum_{k=1}^{n}(k^2 \cdot (k+1)!)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, factorial

We have to evaluate the following:

$$1^2 \cdot 2! + 2^2 \cdot 3! + \cdots + n^2 \cdot (n+1)! =\sum_{k=1}^{n} k^2 \cdot (k+1)!$$

Any hints ?

Comment: The result should be $2 - (n+2)! + n(n+2)!$. You can show this by induction, although I'm not sure how you can derive this result.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let

$$f_k = (k-1) (k+2)!$$

Then

$$f_k-f_{k-1} = k^2 (k+1)!$$

and

$$\begin{align}\sum_{k=1}^n k^2 (k+1)! &= f_1 - f_0 + f_2 - f_1 + \ldots+f_{n}-f_{n-1}\\ &= f_n-f_0\\  &= (n-1)(n+2)! + 2\end{align}$$

**ADDENDUM**

How did I get my $f_k$?  By assuming that such an anti-difference takes the form

$$f_k = (k+m) (k+n)!$$

This general form will produce a quadratic times some factorial upon differencing.  Here

$$f_k - f_{k-1} = [(k^2-(m+n-1) k + m (n-1) + 1] (k+n-1)!$$

We want to isolate a factor of $k^2$ in the brackets.  Then we have to solve

$$m+n-1=0$$
$$m (n-1) + 1=0$$

The solutions are $(m,n) = (-1,2)$ and $(1,0)$.  The former solution provides the form we seek.

Comment: It would be good to comment on how to obtain the "discrete primitive" $f_k$ in this case.

Comment: @PeterTamaroff: I hate to say it, but it was just a lot of messing around until I got the $f_k$ whose difference was the term being summed.  I am not aware of a general method by which one finds an "anti-difference."

Comment: @RonGordon See Sasha's answer.

Comment: @Did: I did, and from my perspective, it has just as much deux ex machina as mine.

Comment: @Vishwesh How will you proceed if asked to solve a variation of this?

Comment: @RonGordon How so? The method is completely automatic: write the prefactor as a linear combination of the polynomials $1$, $k+2$, $(k+2)(k+3)$, $(k+2)(k+3)(k+4)$, etc., and proceed happily and quietly.

Comment: @did: that's essentially what I did.  It's clear that, to get the summand as the result of a difference, you have to express the "anti-difference" as something like $(k+m)(k+n)!$.  Perhaps that's less messing around than I let on.  But still, as with any of these problems using an analog of the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus for sums, there isn't any simple formula for the anti-difference.

Comment: @did: and maybe I give Sasha less credit than he deserves.  Many of these difference equations are solved by replacing things like $x^n$ in integrals with Pochammer symbols, and perhaps that's what he has done.

Comment: @RonGordon Not sure I discern exactly what you say about your solution. Anyhow, the real question concerns the OP, not you: how can they use a solution where the correct discrete primitive pops up as if magically?

Comment: @did: agreed. I will edit to make my solution a little clearer.  And I do see Sasha's reasoning better - but you had to explain it to me.  I didn't get it from Sasha's solution.

Answer (score 5):

Using $k^2 = (k+3)(k+2) - 5 (k+2) + 4$ we write $$f_k = k^2 (k+1)! = (k+3)! - 5 (k+2)! + 4 (k+1)! = G_{k+1} - G_k$$
where $G_k = (k+2)! - 4(k+1)!$, therefore
$$
   \sum_{k=1}^n f_k = \sum_{k=1}^n \left(G_{k+1} - G_k\right) = G_{n+1} - G_1
$$
Since $G_1 = -2$, and $G_{n+1} = (n+3)! - 4(n+2)! = (n+2)! (n-1)$ we get
$$
    \sum_{k=1}^n k^2 (k+1)! = (n-1) (n+2)! + 2
$$

Answer (score 0):

Using k2=(k+3)(k+2)−5(k+2)+4 we write
fk=k2(k+1)!=(k+3)!−5(k+2)!+4(k+1)!=Gk+1−Gk
where Gk=(k+2)!−4(k+1)!, therefore
∑k=1nfk=∑k=1n(Gk+1−Gk)=Gn+1−G1
Since G1=−2, and Gn+1=(n+3)!−4(n+2)!=(n+2)!(n−1) we get
∑k=1nk2(k+1)!=(n−1)(n+2)!+2

Comment: Please use $\LaTeX$ when typesetting math. Use this guide: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: This appears to be a duplicate of Sasha's solution, non-LaTeX'ed, but character-for-character.

Comment: Please do not plagiarize. This can lead to suspension.